# Implementing DataTemplateSelector - want to pass parent's property somehow

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, binding, datatemplate

I'm trying to implement DataTemplateSelector just like it is done here: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/SLTemplateSelector.aspx

This XAML works fine. However, this is not what I want. I want to select template based on `ZoomLevel`

So, I need to pass ZoomLevel into my class `Mobile:DevicePushpinTemplateSelector` somehow. Is it possible? I tried to set `Content="{Binding ZoomLevel, ElementName=MainMap}"` which did pass ZoomLevel as parameter to my selector. But all of the templates inside (DotTemplate, NumberedTemplate, DetailedTemplate) was NULL. And, I'm not sure how to bind inside templates in this case.

```
<m:Map x:Name="MainMap"
            ZoomLevel="{Binding MapZoomLevel, Mode=TwoWay}">
            <m:MapItemsControl 
                ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource WorkLayerData}}">
                <m:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Mobile:DevicePushpinTemplateSelector Content="{Binding}">
                            <Mobile:DevicePushpinTemplateSelector.DotTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>                                    
                                    <Ellipse m:MapLayer.Position="{Binding Location}"
                                        Width="10" Height="10" Stroke="Black" Fill="Red" StrokeThickness="2" /> 
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </Mobile:DevicePushpinTemplateSelector.DotTemplate>
                            <Mobile:DevicePushpinTemplateSelector.NumberedTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Ellipse m:MapLayer.Position="{Binding Location}"
                                            Width="10" Height="10" Stroke="Black" Fill="Red" StrokeThickness="2" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </Mobile:DevicePushpinTemplateSelector.NumberedTemplate>
                            <Mobile:DevicePushpinTemplateSelector.DetailedTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Ellipse m:MapLayer.Position="{Binding Location}"
                                            Width="10" Height="10" Stroke="Black" Fill="Red" StrokeThickness="2" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </Mobile:DevicePushpinTemplateSelector.DetailedTemplate>
                        </Mobile:DevicePushpinTemplateSelector>
                    </DataTemplate>




                </m:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </m:MapItemsControl>
        </m:Map>
```

Comment: Same scenario for me - would love to know anyone's input to how to solve this

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just create another property on DevicePushPinDataSelector and then populate it via a binding?

```
<Mobile:DevicePushpinTemplateSelector Content="{Binding}" ZoomLevel="{Binding ZoomLevel, ElementName=MainMap}">
```

Binding to data within your DataTemplates should be the same as normal, they will inherit their DataContext so should be `WorkLayerData` as specified in your ItemsControl.